# Can't load Texture in onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, libgdx, textures, onactivityresult

This is the Core project :

```
public class GameClass extends Game {

    public CustomScreen customScreen;
    public CustomScreen currentScreen;

    public CustomInterface handler;

    public static int screenWidth;
    public static int screenHeight;

    public GameClass(CustomInterface handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void create () {
        screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        customScreen = new CustomScreen();
        currentScreen = customScreen;
        setScreen(currentScreen);
        handler.PickFile();
    }

    public void onPickFile(String filePath) {
        currentScreen.onPickFile(filePath);
    }
}

public class CustomObject {

    public Texture texture;

    public CustomObject() {
        this.texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg"));
    }

    public void Display(SpriteBatch batcher) {
        batcher.draw(texture, 0, 0, 500, 500);
    }
}

public interface CustomInterface {
    public void PickFile();
}

public class CustomScreen implements Screen {

    Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg"));

    SpriteBatch batcher;
    OrthographicCamera cam;
    CustomObject obj2;

    public CustomScreen() {
        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(true, GameClass.screenWidth, GameClass.screenHeight);
        batcher = new SpriteBatch();
        batcher.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    }

    public void onPickFile(String filePath) {
        obj2 = new CustomObject();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batcher.begin();
        if (obj2 != null)
            obj2.Display(batcher);
        batcher.end();
    }
}
```

And this is the Android project :

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements CustomInterface {

    GameClass game;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        game = new GameClass(this);
        initialize(game, config);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        game.onPickFile("");
    }

    public void PickFile() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
}
```

When the render function in the CustomScreen class is called, after I picked a picture in the Android library, instead of displaying the badlogic.jpg texture I was expecting, it displays a black texture.

This is what it displays :

[image]

And this is what it should display :

[image]

(I know part of the code in the Android project is useless and that I could basically load the badlogic.jpg texture in the Core project, but in the end the point is to load a texture picked from the Android library, but as you can see, I can't even load a texture in the asset folder yet)

I've been trying to fix this for several months now, and I still have no idea how to do it, please help me !

Comment: It does, in the render function. I'll put a screenshot of what it displays. It calls obj2.Display(batcher), which is supposed to display obj2.texture (aka badlogic.jpg).

Comment: I just added two screenshots. One is what I see, the other is what I should see.

Comment: Try wrapping `obj2 = new CustomObject();` like this `Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() { obj2 = new CustomObject(); } });` Just a guess that OpenGL doesn't like loading textures on some other thread. (in this case the Android UI thread instead of the OpenGL thread)